# Kotlin: Usar setters personalizados en el constructor

Tags: kotlin, constructor, set

No sé como hacer para que al crear un objeto los valores de los parámetros "pasen a través de los setters" lo más cercano que he conseguido es duplicar el código, usarlo una vez en la creación del objeto y otra vez en el setter

```
class User(var name: String, password: String, age: Int) {

    var password: String = if (password.length > 6) password else throw  IllegalArgumentException("Password is too short")
        set(value) {
            if(value.length > 6)
                field = value
            else
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Password is too short")
        }

    var age: Int = if (age > 18) age else throw IllegalArgumentException("Age must be 18+")
        set(value) {
            if(value > 18 )
                field = value
            else
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Age must be 18+")
        }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "login: $name, password: $password, age: $age"
    }
}

fun main() {

    val user1 = User("User1", "swordfish", 20)
    println(user1)

    try{
        // This code throw a exception
        user1.password = "fish"
    }
    catch (e: IllegalArgumentException){
        println(e.message)
    }

    // Here we can see if password has changed
    println(user1)

    try{
        // WHY this code DO NOT throw a exception?
        val user2 = User("U2", "swordfish", 2)
        println(user2)
    }
    catch (e: IllegalArgumentException){
        println(e.message)
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero es poder hacer comprobaciones (a través de un setter) de los parámetros que se pasan en la creación de un objeto

Answer (score 0):

Las comprobaciones en los setter son correctas, pero al crear el objeto puedes un objeto usando `var` (variable cuyo valor puede cambiar) en lugar de `val` (variable cuyo valor no cambia nunca), cada vez que desees usar nuevos parámetros simplemente definelos para el objeto creado inicialmente, ejemplo:

```
 var u = User("User1", "swordfish", 20)
 println(u)
 u = User("User2", "jellyfish", 19)
 println(u)
 u = User("User3", "shark", 21)
 println(u)
```

Este sería el código :

```
fun main() {    
         
    var user = User("User1", "swordfish", 20)
    println(user)

    try{
        // This code throw a exception
        user.password = "fish"
    }
    catch (e: IllegalArgumentException){
        println(e.message)
    }

    // Here we can see if password has changed
    println(user)

    try{
        // WHY this code DO NOT throw a exception?
        user = User("U2", "swordfish", 2)
        println(user)
    }
    catch (e: IllegalArgumentException){
        println(e.message)
    }
     
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero el problema es buscar un método sencillo para poder comprobar la validez de los parámetros al crear un objeto.
En tu ejemplo la línea:
 u = User("User3", "shark", 21)
debería dar un error (y no lo da)

Answer (score 0):

Me han respondido a esta pregunta (creo que de manera correcta) aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738548/kotlin-how-to-use-custom-setters-in-primary-constructor/70738919#70738919

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).